# Objects in Kotlin

Tags: javascript, kotlin

In Javascript, you can create objects like the following:

```
var obj = {}
obj["test"] = "test"
```

How can I do the same thing above in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [MutableMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/):

```kotlin
val obj = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
obj["test"] = "test"
```